# Is there an error in C# snippet highlighting

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I've stumbled upon this question - [MVC download file from API and retun as result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790925/mvc-download-file-from-api-and-retun-as-result)

The syntax is valid, but it seems the highlighter ignores @ at the beginning of C# string - ie. `@"\"` is valid string but it seems the highlighter thinks `\"` is just quote escaping and ignores the at-sign at the beginning of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question didn't have the C# tag, so the syntax highlighting for C# wasn't being applied -- it was using a generic rule set.

I've added the appropriate hint.